# array + matrix = array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [name, speed, power, energy];
arr2 = [
  [Ed, 10, 20, 30],
  [Robert, 15, 25, 35],
  [Paul, 8, 18, 28]
];
```

How can I combine the two array's to an array of objects, using the first array for keys and the second one for values?

```
arr3 = [
  {
    name: "Ed",
    speed:"10",
    power:"20",
    energy:"30"
  },
  {
    name: "Robert",
    speed:"15",
    power:"25",
    energy:"35"
  },
  {
    name: "Paul,
    speed:"8",
    power:"18",
    energy:"28"
  }
];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a minimal reproducible example. It is the expectation that you to try solve the problem first before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create an array of objects using `map`

```js
arr2.map(row => {
 const name = item[0];
 const speed = item[1];
 const power = item[2];
 const energy = item[3];
 return { name, speed, power, energy }
})
```

Running this on your given `arr2` gives the following result

```js
var arr2 = [['Ed', 10, 20, 30],['Robert', 15, 25, 35],['Paul', 8, 18, 28]];

var arr3 = arr2.map(row => {
 const name = item[0];
 const speed = item[1];
 const power = item[2];
 const energy = item[3];
 return { name, speed, power, energy }
});

console.log(arr3)
// arr3 = [
//  {name: "Ed", speed:10, power:20, energy:30},
//  {name: "Robert", speed:15, power:25, energy:35},
//  {name: "Paul", speed:8, power:18, energy:28}
// ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I am assuming the tokens `name`, `speed`, `power`, `energy` are actually strings and you forgot to include the quotes.

The Object.fromEntries method takes an array of tuples (two-item arrays) and converts it into an object.

If we zip the keys from arr1 with the values from each array in arr2, we can acheive the desired mapping.

```js
arr1 = ["name", "speed", "power", "energy"];
arr2 = [["Ed", 10, 20, 30],["Robert", 15, 25, 35],["Paul", 8, 18, 28]];
arr3 = arr2.map(objArr =>
    Object.fromEntries(arr1.map((key, i) => 
        [key, objArr[i]] // key-value tuple
    ))
)
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has this really useful method called [`zip`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip), so you want basically that for each of `arr2` but in JavaScript. In other words, zip `arr1` keys with each person's properties.

Below is a snippet that implements a basic `zip` function and then uses it to create the object in the format you're looking for:

```js
arr1 = ["name", "speed", "power", "energy"];
arr2 = [
  ["Ed", 10, 20, 30],
  ["Robert", 15, 25, 35],
  ["Paul", 8, 18, 28],
];

Array.prototype.zip = function(a) {
  return this.map((k, i) => [k, a[i]]);
};

arr3 = arr2.map(p => Object.fromEntries(arr1.zip(p)));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: I always get the same: "Object.fromEntries is not a function"

Comment: Are you on IE or an older browser? https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries

Comment: i am using chrome.

Comment: Newer than version 72? If so, then you should not be getting "Object.fromEntries is not a function" because it's supported.

Comment: v.81, probably I messed up somewhere.